# Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'appSyncClient' - AWS x iOS

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I'm currently trying Amazon's iOS SDK. I've been following

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn

I've hit a snag. Amazon mentions I need to add some code into `viewDidLoad()` on my View Controller but I'm getting the error

> Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'appSyncClient'. Here's the entire code from my View Controller

[image: image of my View Controller code]

I've uploaded an image of the issue.

Comment: Step 5 of your document: There is `var appSyncClient: AWSAppSyncClient?` in the `AppDelegate` class/file.

Comment: Please share the code instead of putting the screen shots directly in the questions.

Comment: Thanks @Larme I missed that in the AppDelegate. I'll try to be more diligent in the future